# How to append JSON comma separated values to a select box?

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a JSON object as follows:

```
{
    id: "3",
    restaurant_name: "Annapurna Restaurant",
    sub_category_id: "2,3",
    sub_cat: "Meals,Tiffins"
}
```

I need to append `sub_category_id` and `sub_cat` to the select box like:

```
$("#id").append("<option value='" + sub_category_id + "'>" + sub_cat + "</option>");
```

How do I append those datas to the select box?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have buit the JSON like this, but rather that way :

```
{
    id: "3", 
    restaurant_name: "Annapurna Restaurant",
    categories:
    [
        { id: "2", cat: "Meals" },
        { id: "3", cat: "Tiffins" }
    ]
}
```

If you have no choice, you can split both categories id and name property, then you can do it simply by calling the object name. In example : `MyObject.SomeProperty`

```js
let MyJson = {
  id: "3", 
  restaurant_name: "Annapurna Restaurant", 
  sub_category_id: "2,3", 
  sub_cat: "Meals,Tiffins"
};


let ids = MyJson.sub_category_id.split(',');
let cats = MyJson.sub_cat.split(',');

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i)
{
    if (i < cats.length)
        $("#id").append("<option value='" + ids[i] + "'>" + cats[i] + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id"></select>
```

Comment: I have to show them one by one in the drop down list. not side by side with comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. (I Understood from your comment on @Cid ansawr)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id"></select>



<script>

var MyJson = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "id": "3",  "restaurant_name": "Annapurna Restaurant",  "sub_category_id": "2,3",  "sub_cat": "Meals,Tiffins"}');;
var cat_id = MyJson.sub_category_id.split(',');
var sub_cat = MyJson.sub_cat.split(',');

$(cat_id).each(function(index, el) {
 $("#id").append("<option value='" + el + "'>" + sub_cat[index] + "</option>");
});

</script>
```